# Timestamp and deletion of updated records

Tags: cassandra

I think insertion/update process occurs like this (correct me If I'm wrong).

Cassandra doesn't delete or update a row in place when you insert a new one matching the same primary key. 
Instead, it insert a new row with a more recent timestamp.
When there is a request for this row, the one with the more recent timestamp win.
During the compaction process, old rows are evicted, only the one with last timestamp stay in new sstable.

So knowing that, is it preferrable to avoid update when we can ?

In my dataset, I have data sorted by date, I update them several times hourly, but once a day is done they won't change anymore for a specific day.

Real time being not really important for this app, wouldn't be better to use an alternate storage/cache (or just aggregate them until I get a complete day).

I think I would reduce a lot impact of compaction (disk usage and available space).